# Mysql inputs data(image) in wrong user id and also database creates new user IDs automatically

Tags: php, mysql

MySql inputs data(image) in wrong user ID i.e when I upload an image, it goes into the wrong user ID created by the database. Database creates new IDs automatically as seen in attached image. I dont know what's wrong. Also I'm uploading via a modal window.[view image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej0DK.png)

```
 <?php

  include_once('server.php');

  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$file = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
$query = "INSERT INTO company(image) VALUES ('$file')";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $query))
{
echo '<script>alert("Image Uploaded Successfully")</script>';   

  }
  }
   ?> 


This is the 'server.php' script.

  <?php

  $servername = 'localhost';
  $username = 'root';
  $password = '';
  $dbname = 'rocco';

 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

 if(!$conn){
echo 'Connection Error '.mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything like `$userId` in your code neither a column like `user_id` in your table. Thus I don't see how you are going to relate the image to any user.

Comment: hi... I'm using ID generated by database as user's ID. Is it necessary to create a separate 'userID' column? The record you see in the image is a logged in account. Hence why the errors. It keeps creating new Ids when no new account is created and as earlier stated inserts image in these new IDs.

Answer (score 1):

you mean there is a table with users id and you have a new column for images to each of userid right?
if so then you should using `UPDATE` not `INSERT` that's why you get a new row of userid in database when you try to insert new image